# When loading a page containing flash or javascript, I get a security error message

Tags: javascript, flash, loading

> "To help protect your security,
>   Explorer has restricted this webpage
>   from running scripts or ActiveX
>   controls that could access your
>   computer"

Whenever I add Flash movies or javascript code this message will show. It also shows for somebody else, so how do I get rid of this message? If I load or access some other website which cotains these features it doesn't show this message. Please tell me how to write a script so that it does not show this error.

Answer (score 4):

If you're loading an HTML file directly (as opposed to through a web server) you can quite often get this message.  If that's the case, set up a local web server (Apache or IIS for example) and develop on that.

If you're already going through a web server, then it's probably your IE security settings are a bit strange.  Go to Tools -> Internet Options -> Security and check the settings there.

Answer (score 0):

This article explains one way to bypass this for localfiles
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(VS.85).aspx

The problem is that locally loaded files run with permissions that ones loaded from a remote webserver don't. So IE tries harder to warn you about them. You can put a marker in the html file telling IE to use the web permissions instead so the warning goes away (and so do the permissions, which you usually don't want anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Another option to not see that noise warning when you load that page from your pc is to write a comment like this:

```
<head>
<!-- saved from url=(0021)http://www.myurl.com/ -->
</head>
```

Where the number is the number of characters of the url.